# jar download with dependencies from maven

Tags: maven

I need a command to download jar with all dependencies from maven., I saw this tool online

https://jar-download.com/online-maven-download-tool.php

but I need to do it from cli. Any methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Maven dependency plugin, especially the goals

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html

and

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html

which download the dependencies and the jar, respectively.

Comment: This worked https://halyph.com/blog/2015/03/17/how-to-download-jars-from-maven-central.html